# UCT for equivariant cohomology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, equivariant-cohomology

I use the definition of Steenrod's equivariant cohomology given in chapter V of the book

N. E. Steenrod. *Cohomology Operations.* No. 50 in Annals of Mathematics
Studies. Princeton University Press, 1969. [Link to PDF](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/steenrod-epstein.pdf)

Steenrod uses $G$-complexes with $G$ in most cases a finite group. I try to show that there is an isomorphism between $H_G^n(C_\ast^{sing}(X);A)$ and $H_G^n(C_\ast^{CW}(X);A)$ with $A$ a $G$-module and $X$ a $G$-complex.

Is there any source which already states a claim like this or which gives a hint?